# Resolving dependencies on a version of the .NET Framework that is higher than the target

Tags: .net

I get this warning when building my project:

> Warning   1   The following assembly has dependencies on a version of the
>   .NET Framework that is higher than the target and might not load
>   correctly during runtime causing a failure: MyProject,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null. The
>   dependencies are: **System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0**, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a; **System.Net.Http, Version=2.0.0.0**,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a. You should either
>   ensure that the dependent assembly is correct for the target
>   framework, or ensure that the target framework you are addressing is
>   that of the dependent assembly.   ASPNETCOMPILER  0   0   MyProject

At first I thought this meant I should update the project reference to `System.Net.Http` so that it points at the 4.0 version - but on inspection it *already* points at the 4.0 version.

More to the point, the project targets framework version 4.5.1, so I don't see how it can be true. Neither 2.0 nor 4.0 is higher than 4.5.1 so the question is, what could this warning really indicate?

Comment: I think the problem here is that you have a dependency on both the current version of System.Net.Http (the one you found) as well as an ancient version, possibly brought in by another dependency (one you haven't found yet).  The old one did not used to be part of the framework, it was a Nuget package.  That's not great, no real idea if you'll have runtime problems.

Comment: @HansPassant - is there any way to get more info from the compiler so that I know what is importing 2.0?

Comment: You can run ildasm.exe on your dependent assemblies to see their dependencies in the manifest.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hans' comment about using ildasm reminded me of Reflector. Unfortunately Redgate got hold of that and it ceased being freely available even in earlier versions.

Fortunately there is [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/).

It turns out that the dependency on System.Net.Http, Version=2.0.0.0 is in System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=4.0.0.0

Yes, it's a defect in the framework.

---

**Fixed in 4.5.2** according to DFTR's comment:

> We upgraded all library code and rest API's to .Net 4.5.2. Everything works magically.

Comment: Did you come up with a method to solve this? The new google API's require System.Net.Http 4. Thus to include it in an ASP.Net website, which has a normal dependency on System.Web.Http.WebHost which depends on the 2.0 version of System.Net.Http...

Comment: No, *it's a defect in the framework*. Nobody outside of Microsoft can correct *that* because we're talking about strongly-named signed assemblies.

Comment: Well, I have to use Google's API. And I have to use it with this version as work has not given me other options. This will be fun to explain.

Comment: We upgraded all library code and rest API's to .Net 4.5.2. Everything works magically.